# Fixing zoom 'jump' when scaling map

Tags: d3.js

I've been working with Jason Davies' [Rotate the World](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/) and [World Countries](http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/4183701) examples and incorporating a few other bits and pieces to learn about d3.

An example of what I have come up with so far is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Libbum/284dc1ed9400f7627d92).

The small selector in the top left corner will trigger a new 'trip' to be displayed on the globe and the centroid of the trip will be centered in view. This all works well, as does panning and zooming on the globe with the mouse.

However, there's an issue with the present implementation when one zooms in/out, alters the visible trip, then attempts to pan/zoom again: the zoom defaults back to the level it was before the trip change - resulting in a zoom 'jump' I'd like to remove [To see this behaviour, load my MNWE, zoom in with the mouse wheel perhaps 3 times, click the OK button to load 'J07', click on the globe holding the mouse button down and pan a bit - you'll see the jump I'm referring to.].

I'm pretty sure it's just me not updating the scale of my projection correctly, but I don't know enough to troubleshoot further. Jason has implemented a `d3.geo.zoom` function, which probably should be capable of fixing the issue. My attempt was to call it in my `$("#sub").on("click" ...` call via:

```
  d3.select("#map").call(d3.geo.zoom().projection(proj).scale(a/2-10).on("zoom.redraw", function() {
              d3.select(this).selectAll("path").attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(proj));
            }));
```

but that gave spurious results after the fact as well.

Lines 344 and 346:

```
var sc = d3.interpolate(proj.scale(), a / 2 - 10); //344
return function(i) {
         proj.rotate(interp(i)).scale(sc(i)); //346
         d3.select("#map").selectAll("path").attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(proj));
         //r.world();
       };
```

are probably where I introduce the bug, as the rotation portion works without issue, it's only the `scale` additions that cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by defining the zoom behavior in global scope.

```
m = d3.behavior.zoom();
```

Then update the zoom behavior with the scale in the transition as shown below this will stop the jump effect you have.

```
d3.transition().delay(250).duration(2250)
              .tween("rotate", function() {
                interp.source(proj.rotate()).target(coords).distance();
               var sc = d3.interpolate(proj.scale(), a / 2 - 10);
                return function(i) {
                     proj.rotate(interp(i)).scale(sc(i));
                     m.scale(sc(i));//update the zoom in the zoom behavior this will sop the jumping effect
                     d3.select("#map").selectAll("path").attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(proj));
                     //r.world();
                   };
              });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OmdLI2qYzjZ9B1mq3QF6?p=preview)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fantastic, that works perfectly. Thanks! The global scope was ultimately my issue I think. I had tried something similar already to no avail. This example clears up why.